# Не запускается Java из консоли

Tags: java, windows, консоль

При попытке запуска из консоли java, получаю ответ, "java" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом. Переменная `%JAVA_HOME%` установлена. java не стартует, даже если перейти в папку где лежит она. При этом если прописать java.exe с любого местоположения, все работает. Как сделать так, что бы из консоли можно было запустить не только java.exe, но и без указания расширения?

Comment: У меня тоже не работает из командной строки, но из PowerShell все отлично работает.

Comment: @zuby_n  у вас несколько иная проблема. Задайте ее отдельным вопросом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверьте содержимое переменной окружения `PATHEXT` для этого можно в той же консоли прописать echo `%PATHEXT%`. В выводе консоли вы должны увидеть список поддержимавемых расширений. Проверьте наличие `.EXE`, если такого расширения по какой то причине нету, добавьте его: `set PATHEXT=%PATHEXT%;.EXE` 
Если переменной нету, не спешите добавлять ее, убедитесь, что в переменных среды пользователя не определена такая переменная. Если такая переменная заведена в переменных пользователя, то вероятно лучше ее удалить. И тогда все заработает.

Answer (score 0):

Нажми мой компьютер->свойства->дополнительные параметры системы->дополнительно->переменные среды и в переменную Path допиши путь до своей jdk(jre) папка bin

Comment: Прошу обратить внимание на то, что я в вопросе указал, то из любого места с указанием расширения java запускается, что говорит о том, что переменная JAVA_HOME(которая содержит путь к java), указан в Path.